# Links in Google App Engine are prepended with the site URL

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, hyperlink, jinja2

I've had a weird issue that's been stumping me for days, and I really need to get it working tonight.  I wrote an app in Python on Google App Engine (I'm assuming this is relevant to the issue), and whenever I include a link with the  tag, the link on the live site is prepended with my own site's URL.

For example, if I placed a link in the home page html to, say, YouTube, like so:

```
<a href="www.youtube.com">Clicky here</a>
```

...then on the live website, it'll be a link to www.mysitedomain.com/www.youtube.com

Needless to say, I get a 404 every time.  I hope this is a simple issue to resolve, I'm really on a time crunch tonight.  Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put http:// before your link, otherwise it is taken as a relative link.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">Clicky here</a>
```

Comment: Aha!  That seemed to do the trick.  I can't believe I missed something so simple.  Thanks!